# STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION (C0000005) while using NtCompareTokens( ) function to compare two tokens

Tags: c, windows, security, winapi

I am trying to compare two token-handles using NtCompareTokens() function.

Sample token value:

- openprocesstoken_handle:0000000000000280
- DuplicateToken_handle:0000000000000284

I am getting NtCompareToken status: C0000005 (STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION).

Why I am getting STATUS_ACCESS_VIOLATION?
Is there any alternative to compare two tokens?

```
PBOOLEAN compare(PHANDLE token_handle, PHANDLE duplicatetoken_handle) {
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(TEXT("ntdll.dll"));
    PBOOLEAN res = NULL;
    if (hModule != 0) {
      NtCompareTokens_t pNtCompareTokens = (NtCompareTokens_t)GetProcAddress(hModule, "NtCompareTokens");
      if (pNtCompareTokens != 0) {
            NTSTATUS status = pNtCompareTokens(*token_handle, *duplicatetoken_handle, res);
      }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: `res = NULL`; use `BOOLEAN res` and `&res`

Comment: Once that is fixed, you've set yourself up for the next access violation (if you're lucky) or data corruption in case you run out of luck. The return value should be a boolean value, not a pointer to a boolean into function local memory.